# Angular2: generate metadata.json and ngsummary.json

Tags: angular, angular-compiler-cli, typescript-compiler-api

Dear Angular 2 developpers,

I am struggling with finding decent documentation on the angular 2 compiler (ngc).

What I want to do: I have a folder containing an angular 2 logging library whose entry point is a 'logging.module.ts'. So far, I have compiled it via a tsconfig file and it worked fine.

Now, I would like to switch to the angular compiler. Yet, when I run ngc. Only *.ngfactory.ts and *.ngsummary.json files are generated.

I cannot see any .js .d.ts or .metadata.json files. (And if I understood correctly, ngc was designed as a "drop-in replacement" for the typescript compiler).

Any hints what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Is noEmit on?

Should be something like this...

```
"compilerOptions": {
   ...
   "noEmit": false
   ...
},
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "genDir": "..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In tsconfig.json,

If you want to generate metadata files, make sure skipMetadataEmit is false:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    ...
    "skipMetadataEmit" : false
}
```

If you want to generate type definition files:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "declaration": true
}
```

Comment: does anyone actually know what the metadata.json files are for?  I've been googling this for 30 minutes and nothing useful.

Comment: In my case it only appears after doing internationlization